# If $c$ is the chromatic number of $X(G)$, does $G$ contain an abelian subgroup of order $c$?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Define a simple graph (called the commuting graph) $X(G)$ as follows: the vertices of $X(G)$ are the elements of $G$ and two distinct vertices $x, y$ form an edge if and only if $xy=yx$.

Question: If $c$ is the chromatic number of $X(G)$, does $G$ contain an abelian subgroup of order $c$?

Notice that the existence of such a subgroup is equivalent to the existence of a complete subgraph on $c$ vertices of $X(G)$. I tried using Dirac's Theorem:

Let $c$ the chromatic number of a graph $X$. If $X$ does not contain $c$-cliques and $$T=\{x\in V(X) | d(x)>c-1\},$$ then $\sum_{x \in T} (d(x)-c+1)\geq c-3$.

Comment: An abelian subgroup A such that |A|=c

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Notice that, the existence of such group is equivalent to the existence of a complete subgraph on c vertices. I tried use the Dirac's theorem: Let X a graph with chromatic number c and with no c-cliques. If S={x| d(x)>c-1} then $\sum (d(x)-(c-1))>c-3$

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include those thoughts.

Comment: @user565189 "the existence of such group is equivalent to the existence of a complete subgraph on c vertices" Is it? That isn't obvious to me at all. How would you know that the subset of $G$ corresponding to that subgraph is closed under the group operation?

Comment: Good question. If not, then there exists a pair  x, y in the set of vertices A corresponding to that subgraph such that xy is not in A. But xy conmmutes with all element in A. Hence the graph induced by A and xy is a complete un c+1 vertices which is imposible being c the chromatic number

Comment: @JackM For any vertex, its neighbours (including the vertex itself: the definition of $X(G)$ adds loops) form a subgroup.

Comment: No, X(G) is simple

Comment: @user565189 Ah, yes it is. But most arguments would be simpler if $X(G)$ had loops ... so let's add loops temporarily for the argument

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how can use it's.

Comment: It seems Dirac won't help much: From $d(1)=|G|-1$, the sum is already $\ge |G|-c$, and already $c\le\frac 12(|G|+3)$ is too weak when every proper subgroup has order at most $|G|/2$.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but it is the unique result, relating the chromatic number and the existence of a complete subgraph that I know

Comment: Some body knows more results relating the chromatic number and clique number?

Comment: Notice that if such subgroup doesn't exists, by Cauchy Theorem c>p for each prime divisor of the order of G.

Comment: Cauchy Theorem: If a prime p divides de order of a group G then, G contains an element of order p

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not true in general (though it would be of some interest to describe the groups for which it is).

Consider an extraspecial group $G$ of order $2^7$. The [independence number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependenceNumber.html) $a(\Gamma)$ of $\Gamma = X(G)$ is $7$ (you can use GAP or MAGMA to check this). In general, it is true that $$a(\Gamma)\cdot\chi(\Gamma) \geq |\Gamma|,$$
where $\chi(\Gamma)$ is the chromatic number of $\Gamma$.

Thus $\chi(\Gamma) \geq 19$, whereas $2^4=16$ is the maximum order of an abelian subgroup of $G$.